# Ruby builder pattern or library

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, builder

I am new with ruby... and now I've started to learn patterns. Is this a pattern or just a library?

```
 require 'builder'
 xml = Builder::XMLMarkup.new(:target => @output, :ident => 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not a pattern, you just instantiated a class.

Design Patterns are a generic topic in programming. There are some patterns specific to ruby. There are books and lists of all the patterns -- just search internet for them.

An example of a generic design pattern: Producer/Consumer Pattern, where a consumer populates a queue with data, while a consumer asynchronously polls from the queue and processes the data (just off the top of my head). It's useful when you have 2 loops running at different speeds.

A ruby specific pattern: Overriding method_missing in a class you make to give it dynamic function names. I think this a pattern I see a lot in ruby libraries.